# Total no of year fig in sql count

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this

```
id name fromdate todate
1  abc   1993     2011
2  def   2006     2016
```

now i want total duration i.e how many years employee spend from 1993 to 2011 here i want to show total years spend

```
id name fromdate todate  total_years
1  abc   1993    2011    18
2  def   2006    2016    10
```

query

```
select * from employee
```

Comment: Are you certain that reporting 10 years for record `id=2` is what you want?

Comment: Do the `fromdate` and `todate` columns only store an integer year, or is there a full date there?

Comment: only int value..

Comment: i want total value i.e 1993 to 2011 how many year passed

Comment: sorry my bad this is not int value

Comment: Update your question with proper value with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do subtract beetween todate and fromdate column:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    fromdate,
    todate,
    CASE ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(todate,'')) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(todate AS INT)-CAST(fromdate AS INT) END as total_years
from employee
```

Comment: this shows error .. Operand data type char is invalid for subtract operator.

Comment: mean your column is not integer in that case you have to cast your value, let me give some time updating my answer

Comment: sorry my bad this is not int value

Answer (score 0):

Your output implies that you want the following query:

```
select id, name, fromdate, todate,
       cast(todate as int) - cast(fromdate as int) as total_years
from employee
```

It appears that you are storing your year columns as text.  This is not a good idea, and you should use a number type instead.  Actually, it would be better to store actual dates in those columns, which would make it much easier to work with.

Comment: this shows error .. Operand data type char is invalid for subtract operator

Comment: @user123 Use `CAST(todate as int)`.  It appears that you are storing your years as text, not a good idea.

Comment: sorry my bad this is not int value